# SQL query for maximum enrollment and prereq courses

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi I have a schema that looks like this

[Schema Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEpyv.png)

I was trying to make these 2 queries

1. Find the top 4 instructors whose courses have the maximum enrollment in all of their courses combined.

   Output columns: InstructorName, TotalEnrollment

   Sort by: TotalEnrollment in descending order
2. List all the courses that have prerequisites offered by a different department.

   Output columns: Course_id, Course_department, Prereq_id, Prereq_department

   Sort by: Course_id in ascending order

For query 1 I wrote

```
SELECT Instructor.i_id, Instructor.name, COUNT(Takes.s_id) AS totalEnrollment
FROM Instructor INNER JOIN Teaches
ON Instructor.i_id = Teaches.i_id
INNER JOIN Takes
ON Takes.course_id = Teaches.course_id
Group by Instructor.i_id, Instructor.name
ORDER BY totalEnrollment DESC;
```

For query 2 I wrote

```
SELECT Course.course_id, Course.dept_name, Prereq.prereq_id, Course.dept_name
FROM Course INNER JOIN Prereq   
ON Course.course_id = Prereq.course_id
INNER JOIN Course
ON Course.course_id = Prereq.prereq_id
Order by Course.course_id ASC;
```

These queries are giving an output, but it's wrong. I need help making the queries correct

Test Data is
tables file is
[tables](https://ufile.io/wqjrk)

data file is
[data](https://uploadfiles.io/eq1bb)

expected vs my output

```
---- query 1 result:
10101 Srinivasan            11
45565 Katz                   9
83821 Brandt                 6
76766 Crick                  2
15151 Mozart                 1
12121 Wu                     1
98345 Kim                    1
22222 Einstein               1
32343 El Said                1

Query 1 Expected:
Srinivasan           10
Brandt                2
Katz                  2
Crick                 2


---- Query 2 result:
BIO-301  Biology          BIO-101  Biology
BIO-399  Biology          BIO-101  Biology
CS-190   Comp. Sci.       CS-101   Comp. Sci.
CS-315   Comp. Sci.       CS-101   Comp. Sci.
CS-319   Comp. Sci.       CS-101   Comp. Sci.
CS-347   Comp. Sci.       CS-101   Comp. Sci.
EE-181   Elec. Eng.       PHY-101  Elec. Eng.

Query 2 Expected:
EE-181   Elec. Eng.       PHY-101  Physics
```

Comment: Provide your test data, the result of the queries you show, and the results you expect.

Comment: @User9213 I have provided the required things in the edit

Comment: The information should be added as text, not as images. It migiht help for you to review how to effectively ask questions here in the site's [help]...

Comment: @CindyMeister in text form edited now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem with your first query is that you're assuming that teachers always teach the same class in every semester, but that's not what the data shows - so two different teachers taught CS-101, but you're counting all of the students toward both teachers. When joining two tables, you probably want to join on as many of the primary key columns as you can, not just one of them.

Try this one:

```
SELECT Instructor.i_id, Instructor.name, COUNT(Takes.s_id) AS totalEnrollment
FROM Instructor 
INNER JOIN Teaches ON Instructor.i_id = Teaches.i_id
INNER JOIN Takes ON Takes.course_id = Teaches.course_id
    AND Takes.sec_id = Teaches.sec_id -- added these 3 columnss
    AND Takes.semester = Teaches.semester
    AND Takes.year = Teaches.year
Group by Instructor.i_id, Instructor.name
ORDER BY totalEnrollment DESC;
```

For your second query, you need to use an alias when you join the same table twice, and also you didn't do anything to check for "offered by a different department".

```
SELECT Course.course_id, Course.dept_name, Prereq.prereq_id, c2.dept_name
FROM Course 
INNER JOIN Prereq 
ON Course.course_id = Prereq.course_id
INNER JOIN Course c2 -- alias
ON c2.course_id = Prereq.prereq_id
AND c2.dept_name <> Course.dept_name -- prereq department is different
Order by Course.course_id ASC;
```

Let me know if there's still an issue with these.